# Can't install VLC throgh software center

Tags: vlc

Installed LTS20,04. Wanted to install VLC. Clicked on Ubuntu software center and searched for VLC. It spins and hangs. The network connection is OK. Please guide me.

Comment: I would probably `sudo apt update` & watch for any errors or warnings.  Assuming that is good, I'd `sudo apt install vlc` and if there are issues there you have some clues (you'll need to have 'universe' enabled if not already enabled, you weren't specific as to what you have installed so it may or may-not be enabled already)  `vlc | 3.0.9.2-1              | focal/universe            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
`

Answer (score 1):

The software center has always had problems.

Try using the command line:

```
Activities(up left corner) -> Terminal -> type in the terminal sudo apt-get update -> sudo apt-get upgrade -> sudo snap install vlc
```

NOTE:
using the following commands is possible, but they are different and can also install a different version and extension packs of VLC.

```
sudo apt install vlc
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

As pointed by guiverc, you must use vlc not VLC. Small and big letters matter.

Comment: Sorry for that, that's my mistake.